# How can I get a dependencyNode's premanagedVersion in Maven 3.0+ API?

Tags: java, maven

I have a pom-packaging project called "testMultiManage". The following content is in its pom.xml:

```xml
...
    <modules>
        <module>sub1</module>
        <module>sub1/subsub1</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>groupC</groupId>
                <artifactId>C</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
...
```

In its sub project "sub1", the content in the pom.xml is

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>groupB</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And what in B-1.0.pom is

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupC</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
...
<dependencies>
```

So, according to maven's management control rules, "sub1" will depend on B-1.0, and then transitively depend on C-2.0.

When I use the following code to get the DependencyGraph with Maven 3.0+ API

```java
DefaultProjectBuildingRequest defaultProjectBuildingRequest = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest();
defaultProjectBuildingRequest.setRepositorySession(getVerboseRepositorySession(project));
defaultProjectBuildingRequest.setProject(project);
defaultProjectBuildingRequest.setRemoteRepositories(remoteRepositories);
defaultProjectBuildingRequest.setResolveDependencies(true);
org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyNode dependencyNode = dependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(defaultProjectBuildingRequest, null);
```

, I get the dependency relationships correctly for project "sub1". However, **the premanagedVersion of "C-2.0" is null**.

[image: what is shown in debugger]
So how can I use Maven 3.0+ API to get a dependency node's premanagedVersion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I use maven-dependency-tree 2.0+, I can use org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyNode to get PremanagedVersion. But Maven 3.0+ APIs seem to abandon this class and only reserve org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyNode. So the question can also be stated as "How can I get a dependencyNode's premanagedVersion with the class "org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyNode"?

Comment: Can you explain why you need that?

Comment: For some research purposes. I just need that for some dependency tree structure's analysis.

Comment: What about looking into maven dependency plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/ (https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/)